# I need help to translate a dialog box in pyqt5

Tags: pyqt5, language-translation

I'm working with Python 3.7 and PyQt 5 under windows and linux. I do not have problems translating classes that inherit Qapplication, but I do not know how to do it with QDialog ...

This works fine:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    t = QtCore.QTranslator(app)
    t.load('my_app_fr.qm')
    app.installTranslator(t)
    calc = CalculatorGui()
    calc.show()
    app.exec_()
```

But with `app = QtWidgets.QDialog()` I don't know how proceed because `installTranslator()` is not an attribute of `QDialog()`

Comment: See https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/176755/internacionalizaci%C3%B3n-en-pyqt5-no-funciona/176916#176916

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The example you indicate works like mine, where app is an instance of QApplication (), but what I'm looking for is that the translation works with an instance of QDialog () ...

Comment: @Sergio It is not possible to run a pyqt script without a `QApplication`. Also, a `QApplication` must always to used to load translators, and this must be done before creating any other widgets (including dialogs). Why are you trying to install a translator on a dialog? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for your answer. I'm working with Qt Designer. I have created an application that opens a dialog from the menu. Each window has its code separately. The main window loads its translator, then from the class I try that the dialogue does the same with a 'slot' or method, as you prefer ...

Comment: @Sergio There is no need to do that. There can only be one application, and that loads the translators for all widgets in all windows/dialogs.

Comment: @ekumoro I try to understand what you say, I would have to include all .qm files in the main window, thus generating a single .qm?

Comment: The problem is solved, I changed the structure of the .pro file:
<pre>
    SOURCES = my_app.py\
                          my_dialog.py\

    TRANSLATIONS = myapp_pt.ts\
                                   myapp_fr.ts\
                                   myapp_es.ts
<code>
Then I translated each .ts file with Qt Linguist and generated the .qm files. Doing this the code that I pasted at the beginning works to load both the translation of the main window and the one of the dialog.

Comment: I apologize for the sloppiness of the previous comment, I still do not understand how to write lines of code ...